# Enforce immutable collections in a Java record?

Tags: java, immutability, java-record, java-16

Java records are used to implement shallowly immutable data carrier types.  If the constructor accepts mutable types then we should implement explicit defensive copying to enforce immutability. e.g.

```java
record Data(Set<String> set) {
    public Data(Set<Thing> set) {
        this.set = Set.copyOf(set);
    }
}
```

This is mildly annoying - we have to

1. implement an old-school POJO constructor (replicating the fields) rather than using the canonical constructor and
2. explicitly initialise *every* field just to handle the defensive copy of the mutable field(s).

Ideally what we want to express is the following:

```java
record SomeRecord(ImmutableSet<Thing> set) {
}
```

or

```java
record SomeRecord(Set<Thing> set) {
    public SomeRecord {
        if(set.isMutable()) throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
    }
}
```

Here we use a fictitious `ImmutableSet` type and `Set::isMutable` method, in either case the record is created using the canonical constructor - nice.  Unfortunately it doesn't exist!

As far as I can tell the built-in collection types (introduced in Java 10) are hidden, i.e. there is no way to determine if a collection is immutable or not (short of trying to modify it).

We could use Guava but that seems overkill when 99% of the functionality is already in the core libraries.  Alternatively there are Maven plug-ins that can test classes annotated as immutable, but again that's really a band-aid than a solution.

Is there any pure-Java mechanism to enforce a immutable collection?

Comment: If you're interested though, kotlin which is built on top of and compiled against the JVM, has in-built [immutable collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html#collection-types) and other fancy stuff, you can get started [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: @Lino - Guessed that was the case.  Yes would be nice to have something along the lines of the Kotlin collections.

Comment: FYI, both [*Google Guava*](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) and [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/#immutable) offer explicitly immutable collections.

Comment: Your claim of "old school POJO constructor" is simply incorrect.  Records support a compact constructor that let you transform the arguments, which are sugar for the old-school version that you're "glass 1% empty" about.

Comment: @BrianGoetz The answer below explains how to use the compact constructor to transform the arguments - I'd overlooked or forgotten that could be done.  The question used the term "canonical constructor" when it probably ought to have written "compact".

Comment: FYI - I write an annotation processor that adds a companion builder for records. This builder can optionally wrap collections in List.of, etc. https://github.com/Randgalt/record-builder

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do it already, the arguments of the constructor are mutable:

```
record SomeRecord(Set<Thing> set) {
    public SomeRecord {
        set = Set.copyOf(set);
    }
}
```

A [related discussion](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-dev/2020-June/006161.html) mentions the argument are not final in order to allow such defensive copying. It is still the responsibility of the developer to ensure the rule on `equals()` is held when doing such copying.

Comment: That's neat, I hadn't known that that's possible in Records. It's also interesting to point out that `Set.copyOf()` doesn't actually do any copying if the input is already an immutable set created via `Set.of()` (or related methods). Just like the Guava immutable collections did.

Comment: Interesting, it's a bit nasty essentially re-writing the arguments, but it does work!  Have to switch off parameter modification warnings.

Comment: @stridecolossus I agree it felt a bit weird when I found about it :)

Comment: You can think of the compact constructor as an N-to-N transform on the parameters followed up by a call to the canonical constructor with the transformed values.  This permits validation (fail on bad inputs), normalization (e.g. reduce fractions to lowest terms), and defensive copies.  While it feels a little weird at first, this is exactly why it is there.

Comment: @stridecolossus If your IDE is warning you when modifying a parameter of a compact record constructor, that's an IDE bug.  While parameter modification is usually discouraged, compact constructors are an exception to this.  You should file an RFE with your IDE.