# Creating immutable Records having mutable fields

Tags: java, record, java-16, java-record

I want to create an immutable record which has 2 mutable fields Date and a HashMap

```
public record ImmutableRecord(String name, LocalDate admissionDate, Date dateOfBirth, Map<String, Integer> metaData) {

    public ImmutableRecord{
        // Date is a mutable field
        dateOfBirth = new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());

        // HashMap is a mutable field
        Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: metaData.entrySet()){
            tempMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        metaData = tempMap;

        //Can I use following instead of above for deep copying the map?
        metaData = Map.copyOf(metaData);
    }

}
```

Which of the following approach is correct using forEach to deep clone every field or using Map.copyOf

Comment: Only the `dateOfBirth` field is "deep cloned", none of your operations on the `Map` perfom "deep cloning". The references in the new map's entries are still pointing to the existing objects. But those (String and Integer) are immutable, so it's not a terrible problem. Your loop can be replaced by `metaData = new HashMap(metaData);` since that constructor does exactly what your loop does.  `Map.copyOf` [creates an unmodifiable Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)), but the values are still the same.

Comment: By the way… Why are you mixing the modern *java.time* classes with the terrible legacy date-time classes? Never use either `Date` class, they were replaced by `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.Instant` classes. Being mutable is one of the many flawed design decisions in those legacy classes.

Comment: This example I have just  used to show the doubt I am having it  is not for the actual project.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in terms of design, generally the responsibility for copying data should fall upon the calling method that instantiates the record. The constructor should *not* be doing this copying, commonly.

Let’s change the name of this record, as “ImmutableRecord” is redundant, and fails to reflect your problem domain. Apparently you intend to represent students, given the admission date field. So your entire class definition could be:

```
public record Student ( String name, LocalDate admitted, LocalDate dateOfBirth, Map<String, Integer> metaData ) {}
```

The modern and immutable `LocalDate` class should always be used instead of the mutable legacy class `java.sql.Date` class.

The calling method should do the copying, as seen further below.

Regarding your attempt to clone the map:

```
    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: metaData.entrySet()){
        tempMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

That copying is *not* a deep clone. You did not copy the *content* of the keys. Nor did you copy the content of the values. You did create another `Map` object. But both the old map and the new map have entries holding *references* to the very same key & value objects.

Your copying is effectively the same as merely passing the old map to the constructor of a new map. Both old and new map have entries that point to the same key objects and the same value objects.

```
Map < String , Integer > metaData = new HashMap <> ( oldMetaData ) ;
```

Your copying is nearly the same as `Map.copyOf( oldMap )` except that `copyOf` produces an unmodifiable map of some unspecified class implementing `Map` rather than a modifiable `HashMap`. But like your code above, both the old and new maps point to the same key objects and the same value objects.

So the calling code would look something like this:

```
Student someStudent = new Student( "Alice" , … ) ;
…
Student twinStudent = 
    new Student( 
        "Bob" , 
        LocalDate.of( 2021, Month.MARCH, 23 ), 
        someStudent.dateOfBirth, 
        Map.copyOf( someStudent.metaData ) 
    ) 
;
```

The purpose of the [records](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature is to concisely define a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. So ideally a record should contain immutable content. That is another reason to prefer `Map.copyOf` over a new `HashMap`.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458073/creating-immutable-records-having-mutable-fields/72458536?noredirect=1#comment128004300_72458536), another reason to prefer `Map.copyOf` is that if the passed map is already unmodifiable, that passed map is returned directly. Less memory used, and less CPU used.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458073/creating-immutable-records-having-mutable-fields/72458536?noredirect=1#comment128004131_72458536), one possible limitation to using `Map.copyOf` is that nulls are *not* tolerated in the map reference, in any of the keys, nor in any of the values. `Map.copyOf` is a “null-free zone”, my own newly coined term.

If nulls are tolerable in your scheme, an alternative would be [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)). And, for defensive programming, make a copy of the map being wrapped by `Collections.unmodifiableMap`.

```
metaData = Collections.unmodifiableMap( new HashMap<>( oldMetaData ) ) ;
```

Comment: It should be noted that when not using `Map.copyOf` but a mutable map, the record should also haven an explicit declaration of the `metaData()` method, creating and returning a defensive copy. Yet another reason to prefer `Map.copyOf` over a new `HashMap`. Of course, `copyOf` does not work if `null` support is needed. In this case, `metaData = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(oldMetaData));` is preferable.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that `Map.copyOf` becomes a no-op when the source is already an immutable map. Which is very useful when dealing with multiple immutable objects, like passing the `metaData()` of one record to the constructor of another…

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I incorporated some of your comments into the Answer.

Comment: @Holger Another good point. I incorporated into the Answer. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your statement that the responsibility for copying data should fall upon the calling method. Isn't it the record's responsibility to maintain deep immutability since that is a property that is expected from it? I also found several examples showing exactly that approach, e.g. https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-dev/2020-June/006161.html, and Brian Goetz himself [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604105/enforce-immutable-collections-in-a-java-record#comment119554095_67604667) that this is what the compact constructor is meant for.

Comment: I can follow your argument for ordinary classes though, where I would also see the responsibility for not having its mutable state modified elsewhere by client code, thus taking care of defensive copies itself.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably best to think of the design decision as binary... i.e., is it immutable or not?

In your case you have something that's mutable.  That being the case just use Lombok `@Data` to build it.

In addition you can:

- add @Builder to provide you with a fluent builder
- add @With to provide you with a copying mutator