# how to make a method not return List, and strive for immutability?

Tags: java, list, collections

If we have a method like this:

```
List<TypeA> retrieve(List<TypeB> sTypes) { 
   List<TypeA> aList = null;
   if(sTypes != null)
   for(TypeB type : sTypes){ 
     TypeA a = type.getA();
     aList.add(a);
   }
   return aList;
}
```

Instead of returning this list, is there a way we can make it immutable not using final keyword? If we return the list there might be chance that someone can add to the list and hence not immutable anymore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713274/java-immutable-collections

Comment: Good question, as per @moo2u2's comment though, it's been asked before.

Comment: Possibly the biggest oversight in collection design: should've had "ReadableList" & "WritableList" which can be combined into "List"...

Answer (score 0):

Collections.unmodifiableList() may help you.This method can convert a list to immutable list.

```
 List retrieve(List sTypes) {
        List aList = null;
        if (sTypes != null)
            for (TypeB type : sTypes) {
                TypeA a = type.getA();
                aList.add(a);

            }
        return **Collections.unmodifiableList(aList);**
    }
```