# How to correctly initialize a list member object in Java

Tags: java, android, list, oop, constructor

I have this class:

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord {
    private Long id;
    private String mBookName;
    private String mAuthorName;
    private List<Page> mPageList;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String bookname, String authorName) {
        mBookName = bookname;
        mAuthorName = authorName;
        mPageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Book(String bookname, String authorName, List<Page> pageList) {
        mBookName = bookname;
        mAuthorName = authorName;
        mPageList = pageList;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return mAuthorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        mAuthorName = authorName;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return mBookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        mBookName = bookName;
    }

}
```

The Page class isn't much but just in case:

```
public class Page {
    private Long id;
    private String mText;

    public Page() {

    }
    public Page(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }
}
```

Right now I figure it makes sense to have two constructors, one for if you have pages already and one if you don't, but is this the right way to go about it? Or do I need to copy the ArrayList that comes into the constructor as opposed to merely referencing it?

Comment: This works - looks fine to me. Copying the contents of the list is an option, but not required. Are you having a problem that makes you think this is wrong?

Comment: @Krease SugarORM is throwing errors at me left and right, maybe that is why

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: `table BOOK has no column named M_PAGE_LIST (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO BOOK(ID,M_AUTHOR_NAME,M_PAGE_LIST,M_BOOK_NAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)` even after I reinstall the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first constructor:

```
public Book(String bookname, String authorName) {
    mBookName = bookname;
    mAuthorName = authorName;
    mPageList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then you will have a new book without any page

The second constructor:

```
public Book(String bookname, String authorName, List<Page> pageList) {
    mBookName = bookname;
    mAuthorName = authorName;
    mPageList = pageList;
}
```

You will have a new book with pages **referenced to the pages (Might be in DB).**

Since the arraylist in java is muttable , any changed data will be modified to the original data (See here [Java Immutable Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713274/java-immutable-collections))

If you are going to used the data without any change to the origin data(Just copy) , you might should use the immutable collection to avoid this problem. But if you are going to used it with some modification ( I saw the class is extended SugarRecord), the second constructor will be alright for you.

Comment: `Remember, write your own custom method to update the "Book" db and referenced "Page" DB both (if you have)` how do you mean?

Comment: This is my failure, I have a wrong mind that SugarRecord will have something like ActiveRecord https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Saving-to-the-database. You have to call twice if you are going to update two tables that have relationships