# Java 9 and tomcat 7.0.73

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, java-9

I am running my java application with java 9 and tomcat 7.0.73 and I am getting following in my catalina.out file.

- Is there any work around to avoid it?
- Can you please help me understand the impact of this error. My application is coming up properly.
- Also why GC daemon thread is created during tomcat startup, is it configurable?

Here is error in catalina.out file.

```
Mar 10, 2018 2:09:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Failed to trigger creation of the GC Daemon thread during Tomcat start to prevent possible memory leaks. This is expected on non-Sun JVMs.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
```

I am using official oracle jdk

```
/usr/local/java/jdk9/bin/java --version
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Are you using official Oracle JDK?

Comment: yes I am using official oracle jdk

Comment: Use a newer tomcat or an older Java.

Comment: Can you please help me understand the impact of this. My application is coming up properly. Also do you know why GC daemon thread is created during tomcat startup

Comment: Judging by the error message "This is expected on non-Sun JVMs" it probably has little impact.

Comment: `sun.misc.GC` was a JDK internal class in older releases, it no longer exists. Tomcat should not be be trying to use this directly. Have you tried a newer version of Tomcat? I thought Tomcat 9 was needed to run on JDK 9 or newer.

Comment: I second the above and previously [made a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917401/tomcat-7-0-73-doesnt-work-with-java-9#comment78793450_45917401) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917401/tomcat-7-0-73-doesnt-work-with-java-9) from you as well.

Comment: if my application in production is loaded once, i.e., on startup, do I need to worry about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was: The JRE I used for the tomcat wasn't the right one.

- Double click on the server
- Runtime Environment
- Choose the right JRE

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change of java or tomcat version,
remove this line from server.xml:

```
<Listener
    className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
```