# Using java 10 apache tomcat 9 is not started in eclipse but its service is started in system

Tags: java

Does Java 10 support Tomcat 9?
Because I installed Java 10.0.1 and Apache Tomcat 9.0.6 and I am running Tomcat through Eclipse the it gives error like

[image]

and on Console:
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradable modules.

Anybody have some solution for this?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7.0.73 doesn't work with java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917401/tomcat-7-0-73-doesnt-work-with-java-9)

Comment: But in my Tomcat folder bin/catalina.sh does not found

Comment: Have you updated eclipse? It may be the version you are using does not support java 10/tomcat 9.

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled eclipse then i got same error.....

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Tomcat 9.0.8?

Comment: yeah......but its working with java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this If I am using java 10 and Apache tomcat 9 then I have to update eclipse as in eclipse   Help > Install New Software > Copy Url as "The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/photon" > Select All then wait for complete the updatation. Restart eclispe. > Delete the existing server and create a new one and try to start the server.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nsN8.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nsN8.png): The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/photon