# Tomcat server - getting error while starting

Tags: java, tomcat

When I tried to start the Apache Tomcat Server v9.0, I am getting this error.
I am using JDK v9 and it is showing me this error while starting up the server. Not sure why this occurs in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Tried to remove that `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` parameter from command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7.0.73 doesn't work with java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917401/tomcat-7-0-73-doesnt-work-with-java-9)

Comment: I tried to run the server using the eclipse itself. Not with the command line.@Selaron

Comment: The solution is still the same: remove that command line argument.

Comment: @Selaron Where to remove the command line Bro? I usually do right click the server and do Debug or Start the server. There is no command line action involved.

Comment: Double-Click Tomcat in Servers view and `Open Launch Configuration`. There you will find command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.!!