# ubuntu server 16.04 - tomcat7 failed to start

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat7

For the past 2 months I run tomcat7 perfectly on my ubuntu server. Today tomcat7 failed to start.
I started tomcat 7

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat 7

Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I checked for the status

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat7

● tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-16 15:47:00 HKT; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6043 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

May 16 15:46:55 www.example.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
May 16 15:46:55 www.example.com tomcat7[6043]:  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine
May 16 15:47:00 www.example.com tomcat7[6043]:    ...fail!
May 16 15:47:00 www.example.com systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Control process exit
May 16 15:47:00 www.example.com systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Failed with result '
May 16 15:47:00 www.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
```

Then, I checked for the log error and I have no idea how to fix this

```
sudo tail /etc/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Somebody please help ....

Comment: did u upgrade java? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917401/tomcat-7-0-73-doesnt-work-with-java-9

Comment: yes, i can see I have java -11 and java -8 here using sudo update-alternatices --config java

Comment: try using java 8

Comment: I have switched to java 8 : java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode. But tomcat7 wont start @Erwin